# Converting ArrayList of Double to double[]

Tags: java

I'm using Apache math library for matrices and one here's one of the methods I'm trying to use:

```
MatrixUtils.createRealDiagonalMatrix(double[] diagonal)
```

I don't know the size at compilation time so I'm using `ArrayList<Double>` to store the diagonal and later I want to pass that as parameter to the above function. How can I cast the `ArrayList` to `double[]` ? I've tried:

```
ArrayList<Double> arr = new ArrayList<Double>(n);
... // Populate arr
MatrixUtils.createRealDiagonalMatrix(arr.toArray(new Double[n]));
```

But I'm getting a type mismatch error since Double[] and double[] are different.

Comment: Change your method to accept a `Double` array. Or convert the `Double` array to `double` array, being careful not to include `null` references.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Not my method. External library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(double[])`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/index.html):

```
double[] diagonal = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(arr.toArray(new Double[arr.size()]));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use 3rd party libraries, I'd suggest you to give [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library a try. It has plenty of useful features, and your case can be dealt in the following way:

```
List<Double> data = new ArrayList<Double>(); // your data
MatrixUtils.createRealDiagonalMatrix(Doubles.toArray(data));
```

See [javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html) for reference.